# How to ensure that S3 upload triggers a lambda function, but copying data within the same bucket does not trigger the lambda function anymore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cyclic-reference

Required procedure:

1. Someone does an upload to an S3 bucket.
2. This triggers a Lambda function that does some processing on the uploaded file(s).
3. Processed objects are now copied into a "processed" folder within the same bucket.

The copy-operation in Step 3 should never re-trigger the initial Lambda function itself.
I know that the general guidance is to use a different bucket for storing the processed objects in a situation like this (but this is not possible in this case).

So my approach was to set up the S3 trigger to only listen to PUT/POST-Method and excluded the COPY-Method. The lambda function itself uses python-boto (`S3_CLIENT.copy_object(..)`). The approach seems to work (the lambda function seems to not be retriggered by the copy operation)

However I wanted to ask if this approach is really reliable - is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter which events trigger the S3 notification.

There are 2 ways to trigger lambda from S3 event in general: bucket notifications and EventBridge.

Notifications: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-filtering.html

EB: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-amazon-s3-event-notifications-with-amazon-eventbridge/

In your case, a quick search doesn't show me that you can setup a "negative" rule, so "everything which **doesn't** have `processed` prefix". But you can rework your bucket structure a bit and dump unprocessed items into `unprocessed` and setup filter based on that prefix only.

Comment: Reworking the structure in way, that it reflects the not existing negative filtering would work in general - good idea. But in this case data is delivered via an external interface and the effort to change the actual s3-path is huge.

Comment: I have the feeling that this list misses one option: To set the trigger up in a way that listens to the event type itself. See my other answer

Answer (score 0):

When setting up an S3 trigger for lambda function, there is the possibility, to define which kind of overarching S3-event should be listened to: [image: Lambda S3 Trigger options]